# Single model communicates between RestKit and other classes, requests fail when not using singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, restkit

In my project I have a singleton model class, `APIModel`, that handles all the necessary calls to an API. I am using `RestKit` and set HTTP headers quite often.

This is my issue:

```
AModel
- (void)makeRequest {
    [APIModel apiObject].getSpecificDataDelegate = self;
    [[APIModel apiObject] loadSpecificData];
}

BModel
- (void)makeRequest {
    [APIModel apiObject].getSpecificDataDelegate = self; // removes AModel as delegate so it ends up receiving both responses
    [[APIModel apiObject] loadSpecificData];
}
```

`AModel` sets itself as the delegate then `BModel` sets itself as the delegate. `BModel` ends up receiving both API responses.

My solution to solve this was to spin up different instances of `APIModel` for every class that needed it.

```
- (void)makeRequest {
    self.apiObject.getSpecificDataDelegate = self;
    [self.apiObject loadSpecificData];
}

- (APIModel *)apiObject {
    if (!_apiObject) apiObject = [[APIModel alloc] init]; // classes own instance
    return _apiObject;
}
```

For some reason though all of these `APIModel` instances never appropriately attach the HTTP headers to the requests, so they all fail on the API’s end. Any models still using the singleton object still work fine.

I am thinking it is an issue with RKClient’s singleton (sharedClient) but am not sure. It is not nil and I can set the HTTP headers and even print them out, but my API keeps throwing exceptions. Is there any obvious reason why the HTTP headers would fail to attach themselves to the request when not using a singleton? **Is there a different or better design pattern I can utilize?**

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193089/what-will-be-if-i-call-simultaneously-rkclient-sharedclient-getfoo-xml-del) and although insightful it does not completely relate to my issue, but is there a way to do something similar?

I thought about using `NSNotificationCenter` but then more information would need to be passed around to allow `AModel` and `BModel` to know what data is for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singletons with single delegates = BAD DESIGN.

As you are seeing, you run into ownership problems almost immediately.

NSNotificationCenter allows you to pass as much information as you want with your notification. It's fine to have a singleton that multiple objects can fire off requests with, but you need to keep in mind any one object that interacts with the singleton, will likely not be the only one.

Do something like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(requestSucceeded:) name:RequestSucceededNotification object:nil];

self.someID = @"Some_ID_You_Have";
//Doesn't have to be an ID, but you need a way to differentiate the notifications
[[APIModel apiObject] loadSpecificDataWithID:self.someID];
```

Then from your APIModel class once you have the data you can do something like this:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:RequestSucceededNotification object:theID userInfo:@{@"data" : data}];
```

And lastly in both AModel and BModel

```
- (void)requestSucceeded:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([self.someID isEqualToString:[notification object]] == YES) {

        //Grab your data and do what you need to with it here
        NSData *data = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"];
   }
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but how do requests work with delegates in the link I provided earlier? I know they are sending the delegate along with every request but is there a good way of mimicking this behavior? I have a bunch of models and it would get annoying for all of them to always receive every notification.

Comment: You can modify your singleton to have multiple delegates, however this gets tricky very quickly. What you have to do is have proxy objects that hold your delegates with a weak reference. Then when you put the proxy objects in an array/dictionary that your singleton hangs onto, it won't hold a strong reference to the delegate.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. Lastly, do you have any insight into why creating several instances of `APIModel` (and remove the singleton) is not working? If it is not a singleton then the delegates would not interfere.

Comment: I suppose it's probably because even though you are removing the singleton model from your class, the RKClient is still a singleton. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with RKClient, so I can't provide any insight into that.